# How can I set a pattern that will output a filename equal to the original filename in SoundConverter?

Tags: linux, fedora

[image]

```
$ uname -a
Linux a 2.6.35.10-74.fc14.i686.PAE #1 SMP Thu Dec 23 16:10:47 UTC 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version: :core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: Fedora
Description: Fedora release 14 (Laughlin)
Release: 14
Codename: Laughlin
$ yum list | grep -i soundconverter
soundconverter.noarch                 1.5.3-7.fc14           @updates
$
```

How can I set a pattern that will output a filename equal to the original filename? E.g.

`something.mp3` → `something.ogg`

And why isn't this implemented in SoundConverter?

PS: `{Filename}` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I selected this option for file pattern: "Same as input, but with an additional suffix." That gave me filenames like: `something.mp3.ogg`

Then I just ran

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp3.ogg" -exec rename .mp3.ogg .ogg {} \;
```

to get `something.ogg`.